# How to check if a file is empty avoid reading the whole file in a submit form?

Tags: python, django, web

I am using django, and in a web submit form, I want to check if a uploading file is empty, but avoid uploading or reading the whole file to get the file size, because it might be huge and take time to calculate.

Comment: For simple text files, perhaps checking the file size will do.

Comment: Yes, but in the django, is it need to upload the whole file to get the file size?

Comment: By upload do you mean your server is receiving the file from HTTP request, or that your server is sending the file as a response? Could you produce a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're trying to do?

Comment: `I want to check if a uploading file is empty`. Want to mention empty file can't be huge. So why do you care? :)

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat)

os.stat(path)

> Perform the equivalent of a stat() system call on the given path.
>   (This function follows symlinks; to stat a symlink use lstat().)
>
> The return value is an object whose attributes correspond to the
>   members of the stat structure, namely:
>
> st_mode - protection bits,
>    st_ino - inode number,
>   st_dev - device,
>   st_nlink - number of hard links,
>   st_uid - user id of owner,
>    st_gid -
>   group id of owner,
>    **st_size - size of file, in bytes**,

so you just do

```
import os
os.stat('/uploaded/file/path')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
>>> os.stat("file").st_size == 0
True
```

by using this code you can check file is empty or not